# Azure service bus rule name maximum length

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I'm trying to publish an event of type `Dictionary<string,object>`and when i call `eventbus.Publish(@event)`i got the following error :

> - InnerException  {"Entity path 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' exceeds the '50' character limit. (Parameter 'ruleName')"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

Is possible to change the limit of characters of Rule name on Azure service bus? Or there is any other way to pass this limitation?

Comment: Azure is a blessing and a curse. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas.  There is a 50 character limit on "Maximum size of any messaging entity name: namespace, subscription, or subscription rule". I'm not seeing a way around it.

Comment: For the record, I've run into these limits before, and we ended up having to re-think how we used Azure Service Bus. As an example: Instead of publishing all the data we wanted to, we had to just publish keys. Then on the receiving end, those keys would be used to look up the rest of the message. PIA.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston what do u mean??

Comment: Can you post an example of a message? That might be easier.  Also, is the receiver of the messages inside your network?

Comment: But... what I mean is... In your case, you are going over your 50 character limit on the Rules. Rules are just meant to be something that you can filter by on the receiving end. (Find all messages were Rule = '123') So instead of trying to fill those rules up with a bunch of text, just use something like an ID or a GUID instead. Something you know will be within the 50 character limit.

Comment: @Paulo Batista, any update on this issue?

Comment: @GeorgeChen the best conclusion that i got was the same that u told me to do.

Comment: If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now this could not be available. Like Casey Crookston said it's a basic quota listed in the [Service Bus quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas). And if you ever check the [AddRule method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.addrule?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_AddRule_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_RuleDescription_), you will find it will throw exception if it exceed the 50 characters.

If you insist the feature, you could go to the azure feedback site and submit this request. Or vote for the existing advice. You could vote for this advice: [Increase the maximum length of the name of a topic subscription](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/18552391-increase-the-maximum-length-of-the-name-of-a-topic)